# Edit NSSet of related objects in One to Many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, one-to-many

I am having trouble figuring out how to keep track of and edit a set of objects, books, that are related in a Many to One relationship on a starting object, author using Core Data.

I have a managed object context and an Author object.

I can edit the properties of the author easily enough such as the author's name.

```
self.author.first = @"Ernest"; 
//save MOC.
```

To get the books, I am doing the following:

```
NSSet *booksByAuthor = self.author.books;
```

where books is a relationship to the books entity and I have previously associated books with an author.

Since the `NSSet` is unordered, I can order it with something like:

```
NSMutableArray *myBooks = [[booksForThisAuthore allObjects] mutableCopy];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"bid"
                                                 ascending:YES];
    NSArray *booksArray = [myBooks sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

My question is, how do I grab a certain book and save an edit back to the MOC.

Pseudocode:

```
booksArray[0].title = @"The Old Man and the Sea";
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? (`self.author.books = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray: booksArray];`). If so, please describe the actual issue.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Your "pseudocode" should work as is.

Comment: The issue is how to grab the right book out of the set and keep track of the book.  since the set is unordered.  In the pseudocode, I am saving that title to the first book in the array with the lowest id but how do I know that record was not a different book altogether such as Sun Also Rises?

Comment: @shallowThought, the books have other attributes associated with them that should not change such as publisher, datedded etc..  I am just editing one thing in this case, title.